# Recursive formula for integral of Chebyshev-type integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, na.numerical-analysis, integration, orthogonal-polynomials, applied-mathematics

Define
$$
I_{m,n}(x,y,r) = \int_a^b T_m(x + r \sin(\gamma)) T_n(y-r \cos(\gamma)) d\gamma
$$
where $T_m(x)$ are the [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) of the first kind, and $a$ and $b$ are constants. Assume that the constants are appropriately chosen so that arguments to Chebyshev polynomials are between -1 and 1.

I was hoping to find a recurrence relation for $I_{m,n}$ in terms of $I_{m-1,n},I_{m,n-1},I_{m-1,n-1}$, but so far I cannot.  I have tried using the normal recurrence for $T_m$, the derivative formula, and many different integrations by parts.  Any simplification would be interesting (perhaps Bessel functions might apply?)  If it makes a difference, the case $a=0, b=2 \pi$ is of interest.

(Here is a related idea on SE, which did not seem to apply directly:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2324185/integration-of-chebyshev-polynomials-of-first-kind-with-an-exponential-funcion

Background: This is related to calculating spherical mean averages after a Chebyshev interpolation. I am currently doing this numerically and this is quite poor in terms of numerical stability and efficiency.

Comment: For $a=0, b=2\pi$ you mean the choice of the constants is $r=0, x=y=1$?

Comment: No, the limits of integration (that makes it a full circle around (x,y)).  r=0 is a trivial case BTW.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to say $r=1, x=y=0$.